# Can't loop through child records in firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2

Hi i am trying to figure out how to loop through a request table with a user key that has only reqdetails. I have tried following the docs, but it's not working.
I just need to filter out all the user key that has only reqdetails only. For example user key of OAJ2WNWQPUfwJCpAJ11FWIA8kPn2 has a reqdetails.

Btw i am following this link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

Here is my firebase console:

[image]

Here is my declaration and constructor

```
  request: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  userkey: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  reqdetails: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  userreq: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, angFire: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.request = angFire.list('/request');
    this.userreq = angFire.list(`${this.userkey}`);
    this.reqdetails = angFire.list('reqdetails');
  }
```

Here is my OpenMapPage method

```
openMapPage()
  {
    let process = this.request.subscribe(records => {
// your logic
 records.forEach(record => {

  var ref = firebase.database().ref("request");
    ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    var a = snapshot.exists();  // true
    var c = snapshot.hasChild("reqdetails"); // true

    var d = snapshot.child('reqdetails').exists();

    if (snapshot.hasChild('reqdetails'))
    {
      console.log(record.$key);
    } 
});   
});
  });
      this.navCtrl.push(MapPage);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the key of your target request or loop on all requests.

If you know the key :

```
ref.child(REQUEST_KEY).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    var requestKey = snapshot.key;
    var requestValue = snapshot.val();

    var reqdetails = requestValue.reqdetails;

    console.log(reqdetails);
}
```

If you want all requests :

```
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    var requestsKey = snapshot.key;
    var requestsValue = snapshot.val();

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var requestKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var requestValue = childSnapshot.val();

        var reqdetails = requestValue.reqdetails;

        console.log(reqdetails);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much